# How to filter data in R or excel?

Tags: r, excel, filter

I have a data that looks like below in excel 2007.

```
Class   Var1    Var2
1       20      27
2               13
2        
2       11   
2        
1       11      27
2               61
2        
2        
2        
1       20      27
2       30      71
2       
2
```

All Class=2 are individuals that are a member of the household (Class=1) directly above it. From may example, this data belongs to one household

```
Class   Var1    Var2
1       20      27
2               13
2        
2       11   
2
```

What I would like to do is remove the data in the individual level and replace it with value of the household level. So from my example, the output should be,

```
Class   Var1    Var2
1       20      27
2       20      27
2       20      27
2       20      27   
2       20      27
```

Is there an easy way to do this in excel or in R? I have 200k+ rows of data so doing it manually would take me forever.

I am not sure how to remove the values in the individual level. But once that can be done, I can just use excels Go to > Special > Blanks functions.

Thanks
Dixi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reading in your data as under -

```
df <- read.table(textConnection(
"ClassObj   Var1    Var2
1       20      27
2       NA       13
2       NA  NA
2       11   NA
2        NA NA
1       11      27
2       NA      71
2       NA NA
2       NA NA
"), header = TRUE)
```

And then processing it as below -

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)

#Flagging each group of 1 and successive 2s uniquely
dt[,flag := 0]
dt[ClassObj == 1,flag := 1]
dt[,flag := cumsum(flag)]

#Copying down the value of classobj = 1 to all other rows with the same flag
dt[,Var1 := .SD[ClassObj == 1, Var1], by = "flag"]
dt[,Var2 := .SD[ClassObj == 1, Var2], by = "flag"]
```

To get the output -

```
> dt
   ClassObj Var1 Var2 flag
1:        1   20   27    1
2:        2   20   27    1
3:        2   20   27    1
4:        2   20   27    1
5:        2   20   27    1
6:        1   11   27    2
7:        2   11   27    2
8:        2   11   27    2
9:        2   11   27    2
```

Comment: Thank you so much Codoremifa! This saves me big time! ;-D

Answer (score 1):

If you read the data into R `data.frame` say `DF`. Then you can just reset values of `Var1` and `Var2` to `NA` first then use `na.locf` function from package `zoo`

```
DF
##    Class Var1 Var2
## 1      1   20   27
## 2      2   NA   NA
## 3      2   NA   NA
## 4      2   NA   NA
## 5      2   NA   NA
## 6      1   11   27
## 7      2   NA   NA
## 8      2   NA   NA
## 9      2   NA   NA
## 10     2   NA   NA
## 11     1   20   27
## 12     2   NA   NA
## 13     2   NA   NA
## 14     2   NA   NA

DF[DF$Class == 2, 2:3] <- NA
require(zoo)
DF <- na.locf(DF)
DF
##    Class Var1 Var2
## 1      1   20   27
## 2      2   20   27
## 3      2   20   27
## 4      2   20   27
## 5      2   20   27
## 6      1   11   27
## 7      2   11   27
## 8      2   11   27
## 9      2   11   27
## 10     2   11   27
## 11     1   20   27
## 12     2   20   27
## 13     2   20   27
## 14     2   20   27
```

Comment: Thanks for this geektrader! This gives me an idea too :-D