# Loop through all the variables in a file

Tags: r, loops, data.table

How can I loop through all the variables in a file? I have a sample code below. my dataset is named as dt.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)

#Flagging each group of 1 and successive 2s uniquely
dt[,flag := 0]
dt[classobj == 1,flag := 1]
dt[,flag := cumsum(flag)]
```

How can I make the set of codes below just loop through all the variables? I got about 500+ variables and its so tedius to do it manually.

```
#Copying down the value of valtype = 1 to all other rows with the same flag
dt[,var1 := .SD[classobj  == 1, var1], by = "flag"]
dt[,var2 := .SD[classobj  == 1, var2], by = "flag"]
...
dt[,varN := .SD[classobj  == 1, varN], by = "flag"]
```

Comment: You should also give sample data.

Comment: Hi @geektrader ! This is a follow up to my previous post. Is it legal to post the link here for the data?

Comment: If it is, here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752153/how-to-filter-data-in-r-or-excel .... I tried your codes because its much simplier but it would also copy the values of classobj == 2 if classobj ==1 is missing which is not what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines should do the trick -

```
dt[
  ,
  setdiff(colnames(dt),c("flag","classobj")) := 
    .SD[
      classobj  == 1, 
      !c("flag","classobj")
      ], 
  by = "flag"
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks once again @codoremifa! :-D